# Find the horizontal asymptote to the following function.

Tags: functions, asymptotics, exponential-function

How would you find the horizontal asymptote to the following function:
$$f_{(x)}=\frac{3e-4}{2e-2}+\frac{e}{2e-2}e^{-x}$$

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about the exponential function $e^{-x}$, in particular for $x \to \infty $ and for $x \to -\infty $?

Comment: I should recall you that a line $y = m $ is an horizontal asymptote of $f$ whenever $\lim{x \to \infty} f(x) = m $ or $\lim{x \to -\infty} f(x) = m $

Comment: Ah , so it's just the first term, got it, thanks.